# Is it possible to dual boot Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Fedora 17?

Tags: snow-leopard, dual-boot

Has anyone attempted this before? Are there any installation guides to follow?

I attempted to install before but I wasn't able to boot into the fedora partition when i was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've successfully installed Fedora on a free partition, the rest is easy. Just download an ISO  copy of [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) and burn it with Disk Utility to a blank DVD.  Then, while booting, hold down <kbd>C</kbd> after the chime to boot to rEFIt.  It will give you the option to boot to Linux (this is indicated by a Tux icon).

Additionally, rEFIt is able to install itself to your system without a DVD boot every time, but I couldn't recommend it as I had some issues with this personally.

Comment: Which partition should I install the bootloader in when it ask?

Comment: For the Fedora installer?- on free space; presumably you have made a partition of free space in Disk Utility before attempting the install. Do you need help with doing this?